# equivalent formulations of optimization problems

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

**When is it sufficient to look at first order conditions of the Lagrangian for determining equivalence of optimization problems?**

As a specific example: consider the optimization problem

\begin{align}
[P]: \qquad \underset{x}{\text{minimize }} \| A B^{-1} M^T x - b \|_2^2
\end{align}

where $M$ is singular.

---

First, if we make a change of variables $y = B^{-1} M^T x$, substitute this into $[P]$, and reformulate as

\begin{align}
[P']: \qquad \underset{x, y}{\text{minimize }} \| A y - b \|_2^2 \\
\text{s.t. } By = M^T x
\end{align}

then I think $[P]$ and $[P']$ should be equivalent (based on first order conditions from differentiating Lagrangians $L(x,\lambda)$ and $L'(x,y,\lambda)$ which give the same problem). Is this the right way to think about equivalence?

---

Second, since we know $By \in \text{Row}(M)$, we can use $\text{Row}(M) = \text{Range}(M^T M)$ and $\text{Row}(M) \perp \text{Null}(M)$ so that we have

$$
\begin{align}
[P'']: \qquad \underset{y}{\text{minimize }} \| A y - b \|_2^2 \\
\text{s.t. } (I-M^T M)By = 0
\end{align}
$$

we have reformulated in a way to retain ONLY $y$ as the control variable and still have $[P] = [P'']$. I see that $[P]$ and $[P'']$ give the same first order Lagrangian conditions
$$
A^T A y = A^T b 
$$
(since $(I - M^T M)By = 0$).

---

I feel like in this case, having equivalent first order conditions is sufficient for characterizing equivalence in this problem. Is that right / why?